# Native macOS window management

Tags: macos, windows, window-manager

I'm wondering if we'll ever see native window management in macOS just like Windows 10 offers it. What I mean by that is the `Windows key` + `Arrow keys` functionality for moving windows around, halfing windows on screen, moving across monitors, minimizing, maximizing, just with those two keys.

I enjoy using macOS on my MacBook on 1 screen with space swiping, but once I use multiple monitors it becomes really cumbersome to use. Tools like BetterTouchTool help but don't offer the ease the native Windows 10 window management offers.

Is there something inherently different with macOS that we can't get Windows 10-like window management?

Comment: I tend to vote to close this question: 1. attracts opinionated answers or 2. off-topic according to the [help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (here: Asking how/why Apple does <some thing XYZ>)

Comment: Hav you tried setting anything like what you are looking for in sysetm preferences : keyboards : shortcuts ?

Comment: @klanomath I don't see how this attracts opinionated answers. I come from an objective standpoint and ask for objective answers. This question is not meant to bash mac os. I am genuinly interested about why apple holds back such a productivity-enhancing feature

Comment: @SolarMike Those keybinds unfortunately don't effect window management thoroughly

Comment: @user1211030 Any answer to "Will we ever see native window management in macOS just like Windows 10 offers it?" would be speculative (except an Apple software engineer/manager not bound by an NDA answers it). So only the second question "Is there something inherently different with macOS that we can't get Windows 10-like window management?" is left. This might be answered by some non-Apple developer (probably specialized on the GUI (e.g. a/the devs of Path Finder or BetterTouchTool) here.

Comment: @klanomath Ok thanks for your feedback. I changed that part of the question

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific in macOS which prevents control of windows through the keyboard, it's just not provided out of the box.

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) for instance provides several actions which allow to control windows via the keyboard (or other triggers):

[image]

I use this to put windows to the left (or right) half of the screen by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Even though helpful, this does not answer the original question, why this is not part of MacOS and/or what the difficulties are in implementing an easy to use system like Windows 10 does it.

Comment: @user1211030 The "why" part of the question is off-topic (see "Please refrain from asking about the following topics as questions with these core subjects are generally closed or deleted: Asking how/why Apple does <some thing XYZ>" on https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic